# convert epoch time stamp to date format in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, timestamp, epoch

I have epoch time stamp like "**1696185000000**" ,I need convert into Month of epoch value, day of epoch value and date of epoch value

Example :
epoch - 1696185000000

month - September,
date - 4 Sept,
day - Monday

how can I achieve this?

Comment: read this carefully https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Answer (score 0):

you should use `DateTime` class to achieve your need:

```
int epochValue = 1696185000000;

DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(epochValue);

// you can use these vars where ever you want

var month = "${date.month}";
var day = "${date.day}";
var dayOfWeek = "${date.weekday}";

switch (date.month) {
  case 1:
    month = "January";
    break;
  case 2:
    month = "February";
    break;
  case 3:
    month = "March";
    break;
   ....
   ....
   .....
  case 9:
    month = "September";
    break;
  case 10:
    month = "October";
    break;
  case 11:
    month = "November";
    break;
  case 12:
    month = "December";
    break;
}

switch (date.weekday) {
  case 1:
    dayOfWeek = "Monday";
    break;
  case 2:
    dayOfWeek = "Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    dayOfWeek = "Wednesday";
    break;
 ....
.....
.....
  case 7:
    dayOfWeek = "Sunday";
    break;
}

// this is what you need bro
// month - September, date - 4 Sept, day - Monday

String formattedDate = "month - $month,day - $dayOfWeek";
```

happy coding...